Is it possible to have a secondary mapping of a field(json) in NPGSQL/EF Core for querying purposes only?
I have a very dynamic json data(extracted from a diagnostic tool) and mapping everything is very tedious, and there's a possibility that the data content might change, so I have to store everything.
Anyway, I used JsonDocument for this field and was able to store the json data. But the drawback is performing LInQ queries is very tedious. Is it possible to have a model that implements some of the fields for easier querying but its contents won't be saved or affect the jsonb field?
